# How to simplify this summation of a binomial distribution multiplied with poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**The original question:**

Simplify $$\mathbb{P}(K = k) = \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!} e^{-\lambda}$$

**The given answer in my textbook:**

$$\mathbb{P}(K = k) = e^{-\lambda p} \frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}$$

**My attempt:**

This is what I have so far:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(K = k)
&= \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!} e^{-\lambda} \\
&= p^k e^{-\lambda} \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} \frac{m!}{k! (m-k)!} (1-p)^{m-k} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!} \\
&= \frac{p^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} \frac{(1-p)^{m-k} \lambda^m}{(m-k)!} \\
\end{align}$$

I can't work out what to do from here; I assume you have to use tricks using the distributions? If someone could explain step-by-step, I would be really grateful!

Comment: Maybe you should write out some terms of that infinite sum in the last line...$$\lambda^k\left(\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^0}{0!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^1}{1!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)$$

Comment: Pull out $\lambda^k$ from the sum, then you end up with $\frac{(p\lambda)^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \sum_{m=k}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{m-k}}{(m-k)!}$ Does the sum look familiar to you? Or after summing over $n=0$ to $\infty$ where $n=m-k$?

Comment: Ah, the sum becomes $e^{\lambda(1-p)}$! I didn't see that, thanks!